# Stuck adding array of tooltips to data template of an array of LEDs

Tags: arrays, wpf, data-binding, tooltip, datatemplate

I've been stuck for far too long on this problem.  I've tried many options and I can't get the syntax correct.  All of the options I have tried either displays the data type, the same name for all the elements, a blank tooltip, no tooltip, or the LED bit value.  I can display an array of LEDs where the color is determined by a bit value but I need to add the name of each element to a tooltip.  I use a data template to display the array.

My most recent xaml:

```
    <Window.Resources>           
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myLedTemplate" DataType="{x:Type sys:Byte}" >
                <Border ... Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LEDConverter}}" ToolTip="{Binding Ledname}"/>              
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myHwTemplate">            
            <Grid>
               <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Led}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myLedTemplate}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                ...
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Ledname}"/>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </ItemsControl.ToolTip>
                        </ItemsControl>                                 
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl Name="hwItemControl" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myHwTemplate}" ... >
                ...
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My  Class types

```
private byte[] led;
public byte[] Led
{
    get { return led; }
    set
    {
        byte[] input = value;
        if (input != this.led)
        {
            this.led = input;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

private string[] ledname;
public string[] Ledname
{
    get { return ledname; }
    set
    {
        string[] input = value;
        if (input != this.ledname)
        {
            this.ledname = input;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

As it stands now, if I mouse over an LED element it displays "string[] Array".  Thanks for any advice you can offer.

Comment: Becasue Ledname is `string[]`. What do you want to display? Do you want to see whole list in the tooltip or for each led there is one corresponding led name?

Comment: The 2nd option.  One name per led.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to a byte array, and in your item template, you are trying to get the led name, but that is in a different array. Your item template will only reference the object type of the ItemsSource property.

Try this instead:

```
public class LED : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _Value;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set { _Value = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Create an object called LED, which will hold your LED Value and the LED name, you can then use an ObservableCollection of this class and bind to it.

```
public ObservableCollection<LED> LEDs { get; set; }
```

Bind your ItemsSource to the collection LEDs, and bind to the properties within the LED class inside your item template.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LEDs}" ...

<ItemsControl.ToolTip>
   <ToolTip>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
   </ToolTip>
</ItemsControl.ToolTip>
```

Comment: I'm working on implementing this, but it's not quite so simple.  My new LED ObservableCollection is one element of a bigger ObservableCollection and our attempts at these changes have caused the LED array to stop displaying.  Once that is working again, the ToolTip should fall right into place.